# Best way to pass values from JTextField into a method?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, variables, calculator

Currently working on a BMR/TDEE calculator. This calculator consists of taking the users age, gender, weight and height, and uses this information to calculate a BMR and TDEE value. I've created a GUI for this, and my final step is to do the actual calculations.  (Some minor changes left to do i.e. changing the height panel but thats irrelevant to this question).

What is the best way to pass instance variables into static methods? My JTextField's are instance variables within my class, and I have two methods to calculate BMR and TDEE respectively (static methods).

Code is posted below.

The variables I need to use are pretty much all the textField ones, and these need to be passed into calcBMR() and calcTDEE(). My initial idea was to make all of these variables static and just use getText() and plug these values into the formula I'm using, which goes something along the lines of:

10 x weight (kg) + 6.25 x height (cm) - 5 x age (y) + 5.

Does this way sound feasible or is there a better way given my code? Any advice on how to do this efficiently is appreciated.

```
public class BmrCalcv2 extends JFrame {

    // Frames and main panels
    static JFrame mainFrame;
    static JPanel mainPanel;
    static JPanel combinedGAHWpanel; // combines genderPanel, agePanel, heightPanel, weightPanel - this
                                     // is a BorderLayout, whereas
                                     // gender/agePanel are FlowLayouts.
    static JPanel weightHeightPanel; // Combines weight and height panel into out flowlayout panel, which is then combined into the above borderlayout panel

    // Image components
    static JPanel imgPanel;
    private JLabel imgLabel;
    private JLabel activityLevelHelp;

    // Menu-bar components
    static JMenuBar menuBar;
    static JMenu saveMenu, optionMenu, helpMenu;

    // Age components
    static JPanel agePanel;
    private JLabel ageLabel;
    private JLabel yearsLabel;
    private JTextField ageTextField;

    // Gender components
    static JPanel genderPanel;
    private JLabel genderLabel;
    private JRadioButton genderMale;
    private JRadioButton genderFemale;


    // Height components
    static JPanel heightPanel;
    private JLabel heightLabel;
    private JTextField heightCMField;
    private JLabel heightFTLabel;
    private JLabel heightINCHLabel;
    private JTextField heightFTField;
    private JTextField heightINCHField;
    private JToggleButton cmButton;
    private JToggleButton feetButton;


    // Weight components
    static JPanel weightPanel;
    private JLabel weightLabel;
    private JTextField weightField;
    private JToggleButton kgButton;
    private JToggleButton lbButton;


    // TDEE and BMR Components
    static JPanel tdeePanel;
    static JPanel tdeeBMRPanel;
    static JPanel activityLevelPanel;
    static JPanel bmrTDEEValuesPanel;
    static JPanel bmrValuePanel;
    static JPanel tdeeValuePanel;
    private JLabel tdeeQuestionLabel;
    private JLabel activityLevelLabel;
    private JComboBox activityLevelBox;
    private JRadioButton tdeeYes;
    private JRadioButton tdeeNo;
    private JLabel bmrLabel;
    private JLabel tdeeLabel;
    private JButton calculate;




    // Default values for gender/weight/height and other variables

    String[] activityLevels = {"Sedentary", "Lightly Active", "Moderately Active", "Very Active", "Extra Active"};
    String genderSelection = "M";   
    String weightSelection = "kg";
    String heightSelection = "cm";
    String tdeeSelection = "no";

    String ageValue;
    String weightValue;
    String heightValue;
    static String bmrValue = "N/A";
    static String tdeeValue = "N/A";



    public BmrCalcv2(String title) {

        // Main JFrame
        setTitle("BMR/TDEE Calculator");
        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        // All JPanel declarations
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        imgPanel = new JPanel();
        agePanel = new JPanel();
        genderPanel = new JPanel();
        heightPanel = new JPanel();
        weightPanel = new JPanel();
        weightHeightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        combinedGAHWpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); // Create a new panel used to combine
                                                            // genderPanel, agePanel, weightPanel, heightPanel below
        tdeeBMRPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        tdeePanel = new JPanel();
        activityLevelPanel = new JPanel();
        bmrTDEEValuesPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        bmrValuePanel = new JPanel();
        tdeeValuePanel = new JPanel();



        // Image panel declaration
        imgLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("filesrc//mainlogo.png"));
        activityLevelHelp = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("filesrc//question-mark.png"));
        imgPanel.add(imgLabel);

        // JPanel layout managers
        agePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
        genderPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));


        // Menu JComponents
        saveMenu = new JMenu("Save");
        optionMenu = new JMenu("Options");
        helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(saveMenu);
        menuBar.add(optionMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        // Age JComponents
        ageLabel = new JLabel("Age:");
        yearsLabel = new JLabel("<html><i>years</i><html>");
        ageTextField = new JTextField(5);
        agePanel.add(ageLabel);
        agePanel.add(ageTextField);
        agePanel.add(yearsLabel);

        // Gender JComponents
        genderLabel = new JLabel("Gender:");
        genderMale = new JRadioButton("Male", true);
        genderFemale = new JRadioButton("Female");



        genderPanel.add(genderLabel);
        genderPanel.add(genderMale);
        genderPanel.add(genderFemale);


        ButtonGroup genderGroup = new ButtonGroup(); // groups male and female radio buttons together so that only one can be selected
        genderGroup.add(genderMale);
        genderGroup.add(genderFemale);


        genderMale.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              String genderSelection = "M";   
            } 
        });

        genderFemale.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              String genderSelection = "F";
            } 
        });

        // Height JComponents
        heightLabel = new JLabel("Height:");
        heightCMField = new JTextField(4);
        heightFTField = new JTextField(3);
        heightFTLabel = new JLabel("ft");
        heightINCHLabel = new JLabel("inch");
        heightINCHField = new JTextField(3);
        cmButton = new JToggleButton("cm", true);
        feetButton = new JToggleButton("feet");
        heightPanel.add(heightLabel);


        ButtonGroup heightGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        heightGroup.add(cmButton);
        heightGroup.add(feetButton);


        heightPanel.add(heightCMField);
        heightPanel.add(heightFTField);
        heightPanel.add(heightFTLabel);
        heightPanel.add(heightINCHField);
        heightPanel.add(heightINCHLabel);
        heightPanel.add(cmButton);
        heightPanel.add(feetButton);
        heightFTField.setVisible(false);
        heightFTLabel.setVisible(false);
        heightINCHField.setVisible(false);
        heightINCHLabel.setVisible(false);


        cmButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  heightSelection = "cm";
                  heightINCHField.setVisible(false);
                  heightFTField.setVisible(false);
                  heightFTLabel.setVisible(false);
                  heightINCHLabel.setVisible(false);
                  heightCMField.setVisible(true);

                  weightPanel.revalidate();
                  weightPanel.repaint();
                }
            });

        feetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  heightSelection = "feet";
                  heightINCHField.setVisible(true);
                  heightFTField.setVisible(true);
                  heightFTLabel.setVisible(true);
                  heightINCHLabel.setVisible(true);
                  heightCMField.setVisible(false);

                  weightPanel.revalidate();
                  weightPanel.repaint(); 
                }
            });


        // Weight JComponents
        weightLabel = new JLabel("Weight:");
        weightField = new JTextField(4);
        kgButton = new JToggleButton("kg", true);
        lbButton = new JToggleButton("lbs");



        weightPanel.add(weightLabel);
        weightPanel.add(weightField);
        weightPanel.add(kgButton);
        weightPanel.add(lbButton);



        ButtonGroup weightGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        weightGroup.add(kgButton);
        weightGroup.add(lbButton);




        kgButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                weightSelection = "kg"; 
            }
        });

        lbButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                weightSelection = "lb"; 
            }
        });


        // tdee JComponents
        tdeeQuestionLabel = new JLabel("Calculate TDEE Also?");
        tdeeYes = new JRadioButton("Yes");
        tdeeNo = new JRadioButton("No", true);

        ButtonGroup tdeeButton = new ButtonGroup();
        tdeeButton.add(tdeeYes);
        tdeeButton.add(tdeeNo);

        tdeePanel.add(tdeeQuestionLabel);
        tdeePanel.add(tdeeYes);
        tdeePanel.add(tdeeNo);


        // activitylevel JComponents

        activityLevelLabel = new JLabel("Activity Level: ");
        activityLevelBox = new JComboBox(activityLevels);
        activityLevelBox.setSelectedIndex(0);

        activityLevelPanel.add(activityLevelLabel);
        activityLevelPanel.add(activityLevelBox);
        activityLevelPanel.add(activityLevelHelp);
        activityLevelBox.setEnabled(false);

        activityLevelHelp
                .setToolTipText("<html><b>Sedentary:</b> little or no exercise, deskjob<<br /><b>Lightly Active:</b> little exercise/sports 1-3 days/week<br /><b>Moderately active:</b> moderate exercise/sports 3-5 days/week<br /><b>Very active:</b> hard exercise or sports 6-7 days/week<br /><b>Extra active:</b> hard daily exercise or sports & physical labor job </html>");

        tdeeYes.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  tdeeSelection = "yes";
                  activityLevelBox.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });

        tdeeNo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  tdeeSelection = "no";
                  activityLevelBox.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });



        // tdee and BMR value components

        bmrValue = calcBmr();

        bmrLabel = new JLabel("<html><br /><br /><font size=4>You have a <i><font color=red>BMR</font></i> of: " + bmrValue + "<font></html>");
        tdeeLabel = new JLabel("<html><br /><font size=4>You have a <i><font color=red>TDEE</font></i> of: " + tdeeValue + "<font></html>");
        calculate = new JButton("Calculate");

        bmrTDEEValuesPanel.add(calculate, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        bmrTDEEValuesPanel.add(bmrLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        bmrTDEEValuesPanel.add(tdeeLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Debugging panels for buttons (remove when complete)
        calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  System.out.println("Male:" + genderMale.isSelected());
                  System.out.println("Female:" + genderFemale.isSelected() + "\n");
                  System.out.println("Kg:" + kgButton.isSelected());
                  System.out.println("LB:" + lbButton.isSelected() + "\n");
                  System.out.println("CM:" + cmButton.isSelected());
                  System.out.println("Feet:" + feetButton.isSelected() + "\n");
                  System.out.println("TDEE Yes:" + tdeeYes.isSelected());
                  System.out.println("TDEE No:" + tdeeNo.isSelected());
                  System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

                }
            });




        // Adding sub JPanels to main JPanel
        mainPanel.add(imgPanel);

        combinedGAHWpanel.add(agePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); // Combine genderPanel and agePanel (which are both flowLayouts) into a
                                                             // single BorderLayout panel where agePanel is given the Northern spot and
                                                             // genderPanel is given the center spot in the panel
        weightHeightPanel.add(weightPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); // Nested borderlayouts, the weightHeightPanel is another borderLayout which is nested
                                                                 // into the southern position of the combinedGAHW border layout.
        weightHeightPanel.add(heightPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        weightHeightPanel.add(tdeeBMRPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);




        combinedGAHWpanel.add(genderPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        combinedGAHWpanel.add(weightHeightPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        mainPanel.add(combinedGAHWpanel);


        // adding to tdeeBMRPanel
        tdeeBMRPanel.add(tdeePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tdeeBMRPanel.add(activityLevelPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        tdeeBMRPanel.add(bmrTDEEValuesPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        // Adding main JPanel and menubar to JFrame
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        add(mainPanel);
    }



    public static String calcBmr() {


        return bmrValue;
    }


    public static String calcTDEE() {

        return tdeeValue;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BmrCalcv2 gui = new BmrCalcv2("BMR/TDEE Calculator");

        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setSize(330, 500);
        gui.setResizable(false);

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is a lot of code to look at, the problem sounds like you could compose a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather easily (like an example with one JTextField, one argument to the function to compute).

Comment: In the actionPerformed() method of the action listener added to the calculate button, call getText() on the 3 text fields, and call the method. Where's the problem?

Comment: My plan was when I press calculate, the actionPerformed method calls 2 additional methods, calcBMR, and calcTDEE (depending on if the TDEE option was selected). These methods would have been static so I would have to change a whole load of variables to be static. You say to call getText and then call the method - do I store the getText values inside variables and then pass these variables onto the methods? @JBNizet

Comment: Yes, you pass the inputs as argument to the methods, and they return the outputs. I don't understand why you want to many fields and methods to be static.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with having too many static methods/variables? @JBNizet I'm not exactly an experienced programmer hence this question.

Comment: All your UI elements belong to one frame. If you created two instances of this frame, each would have to add its own menu bar, panels, etc. So these UI components shouldn't be static. They should be instance fields. Regarding the methods, if they don't access any instance variable, they can be made static, but that wouldn't bring any advantage either, unless you want to use them from another class or object. But if that's the case, they should be in another utility class anyway, and not in the frame. you seem to think that static is inherently better than non-static. That's not true at all.

Comment: Okay, I've removed the static modifiers. I didn't think static was better than non-static - I just confused myself with when and how to use them. I may also take your suggestion regarding storing age, height etc in instance variables, and passing these instance variables to an instance method rather than a static. Although I have something working using static fields and methods. If I were to use getText on the fields, this would return a string and I would need to use parseDouble/int to perform calculations right? @JBNizet

Comment: Yes, you would have to parse the string.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the help, much appreciated @JBNizet. If I were only making one instantiation of the class in my code (which is what I do, in my main method I only instantiate my class once), would static methods be okay then, aslong as they do not need to access any instance variables? I'm not sure I 100% understand what you said earlier so just clarifying.

Comment: It would "work", but it would be a design mistake. Another problem is that if you create the frame, display it, then close it and don't use it anymore, having all the fields static will prevent the garbage collector to reclaim the memory they occupy, because they're still referenced by the class, although no actual instance use them anymore.

Comment: Okay I've understood I think. The method in question also depends on creating an object anyway, because in the constructor the main JFrame is created. Without creating an object, there would be no way for the user to enter the information which is actually needed for the methods. Is this a valid way of thinking about it also? @JBNizet

Comment: My previous comment was about static fields. If the method doesn't use any instance variable, as I said, making it static does not harm. It allows to call the method in another context, without having to create a frame. But if that's the goal, the methods should be moved to another class.

Comment: The goal isn't to call the method without creating the frame - the frame is needed for the user to enter information which the method will then use. @JBNizet

Comment: The goal *now* isn't to do that. But you could want to allow that *later*. Or you could write a unit test to see if the method works fine. Why have to create a frame to test this method although it doesn't **need** one. Design is not only about making something work. It's also about making things easy to evolve, reuse, test, maintain.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Because I changed all the fields from static to non-static my only option in this case would be to make the methods non-static aswell, as a static method won't be able to access these fields. If later on down the line I decide to make this method static for testing etc, do I simply just change the variables used in this method to static? @JBNizet.
Is there any disadvantages to using a static method straight off the bat, besides garbage collection?

Comment: Sorry for going back and forth, I just want to make sure I learn from this so I don't make similar design mistakes in the future.

Comment: No. You pass the inputs as *arguments* to the methods.

Comment: That's what I'm already doing. E.g. I have a variable String ageValue = ageTextField.getText();, parsing this and passing ageValue to my CalcBMR/CalcTDEE method. Is this what you suggest @JBNizet